# Tracking SQL Server change on specific column

Tags: sql-server

Trying to find out what stored procedure is changing a value in a column. I have a bit column that is getting flipped back and forth throughout the day and I would like to pin point which procedure(s) is doing it.

Any straightforward way to do this? (I looked into CDC but that didn't seem to have a way to track the procedure(s) making the change)

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think off is a trigger and capture the offending procedure that way.

Answer (score 0):

By "straightforward", do you really mean simple? Use SSMS to generate a script of all your stored procedures in a single file. Then just look for that column name using any editor you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I went with the solution below.

```
SELECT 
    qStats.last_execution_time AS [ExecutedAt],
    qTxt.[text] AS [Query], qTxt.number, qTxt.[dbid]
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qStats
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qStats.sql_handle) AS qTxt
```